# About the Frenet apparatus: are these expressions wrong?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I'm using Keti Tenenblat's "Introduction to differential geometry" text, and according to the book, we have:

$$T'(s) = K(s)N(s)$$
$$N'(s) =  -K(s)T(s) - \tau(s)B(s)$$
$$B'(s) = \tau(s)N(s)$$

where $T(s)$, $N(s)$, $K(s)$, $\tau(s)$ are defined to be, respectively, the tangent vector, the normal vector, the curvature and the torsion and by definition $B(s) = T(s) \times N(s)$.

However, according to wikipedia, the correct formulas would be (and they only agree about $T'(s)$):

$$T'(s) = K(s)N(s)$$
$$N'(s) =  -K(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s)$$
$$B'(s) = -\tau(s)N(s)$$

What's going on here? I'm trying to solve an exercise about computing the curvature and torsion of the tangent indicatrix that relies on these equations, and it can be found on both hers and O Neil's "Elementary differential geometry" text. However, the former uses the first set of equations and the latter seems to use the second. [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrenetFormulas.html) agrees on the second as well.

Comment: it seems the torsion is defined with the opposite sign in one of the sources.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Comment: I think Brazilians seem to be fond of the reversed sign convention from the rest of us. DoCarmo also has the sign switched on torsion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in the comments.